# Searching Gmail messages while excluding the reply history?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I have a business conversation going on and I'm trying to find a particular message I'm sure was part of it.  Let's say it includes the term "widget".  But the problem is there were (for example) 3 messages with that term.  Now by itself that would be fine, I'd search for that term and see three results and read them and find the one I want.  But the problem is that one of those messages had a very long back-and-forth so there's a long re: history and that term is repeated each and every time.  So when I search I get 590 matches instead of 3.

I want to search without including all the quoted replies. So that only the typed messages is included in the search.

Possible?

Answer (score 2):

You *might* be able to do something with the negation filter. Many (most?) email clients add something like "Re:" or "Fw:" to the subject when replying or forwarding a message.

So perhaps something like this would suit:

```
widget -subject:"re:"
```

This should return all messages with "widget" in the message but exclude messages with "re:" in the subject of the message.

It's not perfect, but at least in my tests it did reduce the number of search results I got back.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

At this time is not possible exclude content from the quoted replies when doing a search from the Gmail web UI.

## Explanation

Gmail doesn't include search features such wildcards or regular expressions.

## Alternatives

Use the Gmail API, Google Apps Script or third party application that include search features like wildcards or regular expressions.

## References

- [Search in Gmail - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6593?hl=en)
- [Use Regular Expressions to Find Anything in your Gmail Mailbox - Digital Inspiration](http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-search/21623/)

Comment: Your Explaination [sic] was shorter than your "Short answer" :)   Any examples of "third party application"s that do this?

Comment: Ups! Thanks for the remark. Regarding the third party app, sorry I don't know about one yet but I'm confident that should several. Maybe at superuser.com or sofware recommendations could help with that. In the meantime I added a reference. Maybe later I could extend my answer.